# WIll images sized on my phone be the same size on another phone?

Tags: android, layout, dimensions, clipping

I use a few small images on my app and I was wondering if (and how) I could ensure that the size of the image is relative to the size of the phone?

Also, is there a way to shrink my layout on smaller phones so each layout fits within the screen - like if a random string (longer than others) would downsize in font so the whole layout was ensured to fit on the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to play with property android:layout_weight = "" for the fields you want to display, and see is that what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read through the documentation on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), as it has lots of good tips on things to do or not do to make sure that your app will render properly on different sized screens.